# Difference in Closures between Javascript and Lua

Tags: javascript, lua, closures, scope

Why is it that these two seemingly identical pieces of code behave differently in Javascript and Lua?

Lua:

```lua
function main()
    local printFunctions={}
    local i,j
    for i=1,10 do
        local printi = function()
            print(i)
        end
        printFunctions[i]=printi
    end
    for j=1,10 do
        printFunctions[j]()
    end
end
main()
```

Javascript:

```js
function main()
{
    var printFunctions=[]
    var i,j;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        var printi = function()
        {
            console.log(i);
        }
        printFunctions[i]=printi;
    }
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        printFunctions[j]();
    }
}
main()
```

The example in Lua prints `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, but the example in Javascript prints `10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10`. Can anybody explain the difference between closures in Javascript and Lua that causes this to happen? I'm coming from a Javascript background, so please focus on the Lua side.

I attempted to explain this on [my blog](http://flightodyssey.blogspot.com/2013/09/closure.html), but I'm not sure if my explanation is correct, so any clarification would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone, now I understand. This slightly modified version of the Lua code prints 10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 as expected

```
function main()
    local printFunctions={}
    local i,j,k
    for i=1,10 do
        k=i
        local printi = function()
            print(k)
        end
        printFunctions[i]=printi
    end
    for j=1,10 do
        printFunctions[j]()
    end
end

main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's as simple as the following:

Lua `local` variables are scoped only to the nearest `do-end` block, while JavaScript variables declared with `var` are scoped to the nearest function boundaries.  Closures get over this point by placing them in their own individual scope in a function, solving the problem of scope.

About your question regarding `local i, j` being in the outer scope, the for statement in Lua creates the scope of the counter being used in the block scope, even if there is a variable declaration in the outer scope.  The documentation says ([reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5)):

> The loop variable v is local to the loop; you cannot use its value after the for ends or is broken. If you need this value, assign it to another variable before breaking or exiting the loop.

This means that the `var` initialisation is made local to the for loop scope, so placing `local i, j` in the outer scope has no effect.  This can be seen in an equivalent to Lua's for statement, given in the documentation:

```
do
    local var, limit, step = tonumber(e1), tonumber(e2), tonumber(e3)
    if not (var and limit and step) then error() end
    while (step > 0 and var <= limit) or (step <= 0 and var >= limit) do
        local v = var
        block
        var = var + step
    end
end
```

However, JavaScript's for statement varies significantly ([reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.3)):

```
IterationStatement : for ( var VariableDeclarationListNoIn ; Expressionopt ; Expressionopt ) Statement
```

Because the declaration of the for loop is the same as any ordinary variable declaration, it's equivalent to placing it outside the loop, much different to how the Lua for loop works.  The next version of ECMAScript (ES6) plans to introduce the `let` keyword, which in a for loop will have a similar meaning to how Lua's for loop works:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) setTimeout(function () { console.log(i); }, 9); // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) setTimeout(function () { console.log(i); }, 9); // 10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
```

Comment: But in both cases `i` and `j` were declared in the outermost scope (within the `main` function), so they should have the same scope in both languages.

Comment: @FlightOdyssey: thats not true for the Lua case. Lua for loops always declare a new variable so the variable in the loop is a new variable each iteration. The  `local i` you made declaration will end up being shadowed and ignored (if you remove it the result should be the same).

Comment: @FlightOdyssey A good Lua IDE would show you variable shadowing in an outline, unused variables and unused assigned values in the editor and multiple local variables with the same name (due to the shadowing) in the debugger. (Sorry, I can't refer you to the one I built.)